# How do I change background colour of .active class to match custom hover background colour?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar (inside a Scrollspy component) in Bootstrap 3 with the following code:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="tab1"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li class="tab2"><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li class="tab3"><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</body>

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .tab1> a:hover {
background-color: #53D8D4;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .tab2> a:hover {
background-color: #2FA70A;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .tab3 > a:hover {
background-color: #E3BF13;
}
```

I want the background colour of the Bootstrap active class to match the hover bg colour for each tab.

I have tried the following CSS but it doesn't work:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .tab1 > .active a {
background-color: #53D8D4;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .tab2 > .active a {
background-color: #2FA70A;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .tab3 > .active a {
background-color: #E3BF13;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is `.active` a wrapper for `a`, or an applied class for `a` or `.tab#`? As I see it you're telling the css to select the anchor inside an `.active` element, which is a direct child of a tab element. Without seeing what the html looks like with the `active` class applied I'd assume `.active a` needs to be `a.active` or `.tab1.active`;

Comment: .active is the default Bootstrap class.

Comment: The html with the .active class applied looks like this:

<li class="tab1 active"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>

Comment: Then your css should be `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .tab3.active > a`. You're selecting a class that is tab# and has the active class applied. `>` is for selecting direct descendants.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much.